# Валидация поля регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно реализовать валидацию для поля. В поле можно вводить только латинские буквы,  дефис и пробел. Если в поле есть другие символы то ошибка.

Comment: Что пробовал? Что не получилось?

Comment: Regexp. Я очень плохо знаю регулярки, поэтому и попросил помощи.

Comment: @Артем можно вводить только  дефис и пробел?

Comment: Латинские буквы,  дефис и пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var rgxp = /[a-zA-Z-\s]/;

function reg() {
  if (!rgxp.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode))) {
    console.error('not allowed char');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.clear();
    }, 3000);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input2" onkeypress='reg()' />
```

Comment: А без регулярки ничего не работает!

Comment: @lampa объяснитесь

Comment: у тс указано несколько "требований": пробел, дефис и символы! Что он подразумевал под символами можно только гадать. И второе - в случае, если текст в поле не проходит условия, то нужно выдавать ошибку. У вас ни того, ни другого нет.

Comment: @lampa автор ответа должен гадать, как автор вопроса будет выводить ошибки? дан "голый", рабочий пример для дальнейшей работы с ним

Answer (score 2):

Проверку можно сделать чисто на HTML, в данном случае HTML5. Единственное где использовал JavaScript это для задания кастомного сообщения об ошибке.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="a-zA-Z -" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Допустимы только: латинские буквы, пробел и тире.')">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: pattern срабатывает только при сабмите формы и не валидирует "на лету"

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да, но в вопросе и нету требований о проверке на лету.